# Distance from a point to a plane without DirectX/XNA in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, geometry

Is there a simple way of doing such mathematical/geometrical calculations without the big graphic libraries?
For my interest, those libraries would only be a big bloat as I only need some mathematics, no rendering, nothing else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There you go : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-PlaneDistance.html or http://mathinsight.org/distance_point_plane#distance_formula_2

You just have to implement this simple formula.

Comment: Ok, you are right, impementing it on my own was probably faster then searching for some solution. I just saw, that most functions are eg. in DirectX, but using System.Windows.Media.Media3D is also helpful here.